# In Ubuntu: "service networking restart" and "resolvconf restart" does not take effect until reboot

Tags: networking, ubuntu, dns, routing

I have a situation where I am using two ISPs, I have a program that periodically pings an address and if it is down assumes that the ISP has a problem and changes the default route and DNS server entries in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/tail files, respectively. It changes these settings to be pointed to the backup ISP. I then run

```
sudo service networking restart 
sudo /etc/init.d/resolvconf restart.
```

However, this does not change the default route (as displayed by ip route ls) or the DNS servers in /etc/resolv.conf. It requires a reboot. How can I get these settings activated without a reboot?

Comment: Neither of the commands you displayed changes the default route, nor the DNS. In order to do that, you will have to specify both such things yourself. What is it that you are trying to do, **exactly**?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae Thanks.. I have two DSL modems from two different ISPs and each one provide a set of DNS server addresses.  One is the main ISP and the other is a fallback ISP with a lower bandwidth. WHen the main ISP is down, I am trying to change the default route to the IP address of the DSL modem of the backup ISP and the DNS servers which that backup ISP provides.  Changing the relevant entries in the two files work after reboot. I want to avoid that. I can use ip route command also to dynamically change the default route.Is that persistent across boots? How about changing DNS settings?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae If my approach is wrong, please let me know the correct way to handle such situation.

Comment: Pls read my answer. Took me a little time to write it up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing of what I am about to tell you is persistent across reboots, which I  presume is what you wish because, apparently, you have an unstable situation. If not, let me know.

I assume you do **not** have a static IP (again, if so, pls let me know). Does the DHCP server of Provider 1 stay on when the line is down? If **not**, then

```
 sudo ifdown eth0
 sudo ifup   eth0
```

will give you the new configuration. But, if instead the DHCP server of Provider 1 **does** stay on, then you will have to do it manually.

1. Change route:

   ```
   sudo ip route del default 
   sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.121 dev eth0
   ```

   where I assumed you are connected via ethernet, and that the IP address of the second modem is 192.168.1.121, if not change accordingly.
2. Change DNS, simplest is: edit (as sudo) `/etc/resolv.conf`, delete the lines with the previous DNSes, then add the two following lines:

   ```
   nameserver 1.2.3.4
   nameserver 9.8.7.6
   ```

(substitute with your values).

If you find this annoying, you can automate it as follows: create an *executable* (!) file, call it `line2`, with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo ip route del default 
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.1.121 dev eth0
sed -i --follow-symlinks 's/First.Old.DNS.IP./First.New.DNS.IP/' /etc/resolv.conf
sed -i --follow-symlinks 's/Second.Old.DNS.IP./Second.New.DNS.IP/' /etc/resolv.conf
```

and now executing `line2` will give you the new connection.

There are other, more elegant ways to change DNSes (using `resolvconf`, writing to `/etc/resolvconf.d`) but since you seem to have a frequent problem nothing is as easy as this.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. I am NOT using DHCP. I understand the ip route commands and they do change the default route without the need to reboot. My problem can now be narrowed to changing nameservers without reboot. Actually I do not even mind if the changes do not persist across a reboot. Merely changing the entries in the DNS config files do not automatically change the DNS servers. **How do I get the DNS entries in the config file to take effect without a reboot?** That is now my narrow problem. Ubuntu does not recommend changing /etc/resolv.conf directly.

Comment: @Samir You change DNSes like I described above, and the changes take place immediately, without doing anything else. The reason why Linux (not just Ubuntu) does not recommend changing DNSes directly in the file is that  your Network Manager will overwrite it. But since you are not calling network manager here, nothing wrong will happen to you.

Comment: @Samir you can check the set of DNS you are using with `nmcli dev list iface eth0`.

Comment: You are right about editing /etc/resolv.conf directly in the absence of network manager. Tried it. Works well. I have accepted your answer. Solves my problem. By the way, I am curious what  _/etc/init.d/resolvconf restart_ does? What is this _resolvconf_ service listed by _service --status-all_?

Comment: The nmcli command is part of Network Manager and I am not a fan of Network Manager and have removed it.

Comment: @Samir resolvconf is a package which ahndles automatic setup of DNS servers, mostly from network manager, but also from openvpn, ppp, and so on. IMHO, it is an inconvenience in fast-changing situations like yours